# How to use a custom variable for the scheme in a rewrite rule in nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect

Is there a way to get nginx to treat a custom variable the same as it treats the $scheme in a rewrite rule? For instance:

```
rewrite ^/redirect http://example.com;
# and
rewrite ^/redirect_with_scheme $scheme://example.com;
```

will both result in a 302 redirect being sent to the client. However, this:

```
set $real_scheme $scheme;
rewrite ^/redirect_with_real_scheme $real_scheme://example.com;
```

will result in a server side rewrite to a file that doesn't necessarily exist and then a 404 to the client. For what it's worth, this:

```
set $real_scheme $scheme;
rewrite ^/redirect_with_real_scheme $real_scheme://example.com redirect;
```

will give the desired result of sending a 302 to the client. Unfortunately, I have a lot of redirects set up this way and I would rather not update all of them with the `redirect` directive if it's not necessary.

If it's helpful, I'm using Nginx 1.6.2.

Comment: Why do you need another variable for this ?

Comment: I'm using a load balancer to terminate TLS and send x-forwarded-proto, thus, $scheme is always http. $real_scheme is set based on x-forwarded-proto or $scheme if that header doesn't exist. I want my rewrites to stay on the same scheme that was originally requested.

Comment: Ok. I'm afraid your only option is to add the redirect flag.

Comment: Yeah, that's the conclusion I've come to as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://nginx.org/r/rewrite) states:

> If a replacement string starts with “`http://`”, “`https://`”, or “`$scheme`”, the processing stops and the redirect is returned to a client.

If you start the URL with some other variable, you will need to express the intention to `redirect` explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot reproduce your problem.

I tried the following minimal configuration, every `rewrite` working as expected (HTTP 302s):

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include mime.types;
    server {
        listen       80;

        set $real_scheme $scheme;
        rewrite ^/redirect http://localhost;
        rewrite ^/redirect_with_scheme $scheme://localhost;
        rewrite ^/redirect_with_real_scheme $real_scheme://localhost;
    }
}
```

Could you provide me with a minimal configuration able to demonstrate the faulty `rewrite` rules?